# 8G SD card showing 30M

Tags: sd-card

I have a 8GB SD card.

When inserted it show no partitions:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdd
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdd    8:48   1 30.6M  0 disk
```

The `fdisk` say:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 30.6 MiB, 32096256 bytes, 62688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

It is about two years since I used it. Then I first used it with a raspberry and then went on to do some disk hacking – but I do not really recall what I did. I remember it ended up with 30M though.

A dump of the disk using `dd` show it only has zero bytes.

Is it likely corrupt? How to investigate further? Any tools that can yield some more information about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The card is almost certainly defective.

I had a similar issue, and asked the manufacturer (Sandisk). As it was new it was replaced under warranty.

I have seen a couple of similar reports, but no solution.

Comment: Afraid you are correct. Not able to get any further with this card.